# How to create a block from lines

Tags: prog-mode

In various programming modes, assuming I have a few lines of code like this :

```
foo()
bar()
```

And I want to turn it into a block (say, and if of some sort)

```
if (something) {
  foo()
  bar()
}
```

Is there, in general, a more clever way than :

- selecting the region
- yaking it
- typing the `if...` line
- pasting the region

I'm probably just missing the name of something ("wrapping" ?)

Comment: With the built-in electric-pair-mode, if you type `{` while a region is selected, it will put a pair of `{}` around the selected region. It might not adjust the indentation appropriately itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Using `yasnippet`

You did not mention what programming language major mode you are working in. So let me provide an example for `c-mode`.

### First time setup

**Step 1:** Install `yasnippet`

You will need to install the [`yasnippet`](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet) package (also available from Melpa) to implement the below solution.

*Check out [this wonderful introduction to yasnippet](http://cupfullofcode.com/blog/2013/02/26/snippet-expansion-with-yasnippet/index.html)* especially if you are a first time user.

**Step 2:** Create a snippet for `if` condition for your major mode.

By default `yasnippet` picks up snippets saved in the `~/.emacs.d/snippets/` directory. Within that directory, you would have a directory for each of the major modes for which you plan to use `yasnippet`. So that directory would be `c-mode/` in this case. Save the below code snippet as `~/.emacs.d/snippets/c-mode/if` *file*.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: if
# key: if
# expand-env: ((yas-indent-line 'auto) (yas-also-auto-indent-first-line t) (yas-wrap-around-region t))
# --
if (${1:some_condition}) {
  $0
}
```

Take note of the `(yas-wrap-around-region t)` portion in the `expand-env:` line above. That is what will allow you to select a region and wrap it with the snippet expansion. The other options in that line are for auto-indentation convenience.

**Step 3:** Load your new snippet using `M-x yas-reload-all`.

### Using the snippet once everything is set

**Step 1:** Select the code which you want to wrap with `if` condition.

Suppose this is the code:

```c
foo();
bar();
```

**Step 2:** Insert your snippet

- `M-x yas-insert-snippet`
- Select the `if` snippet

### Result

```c
if (some_condition) {
  foo();
  bar();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) for this. First, write in your `if` statement, leaving the point where the pipe `|` is:

```
if (condition) {|}
foo();
bar();
```

Then call the function `sp-slurp-hybrid-sexp` twice:

```
if (condition) {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

See the [`smartparens` wiki page](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Hybrid-S-expressions) for more info on "hybrid s-exps".